# Chart not rendering on Partner Portal Dashboard

Tags: dynamics-crm-portals

We are using the Portal solution with Dynamics v8.  When the user logs in the charts on the dashboard does not render, it only displays "loading".  The entity lists does render correctly.  I am testing the Partner Dashboard Template that came OOB.  I did check that the "chart id" and "viewid" are correct.  The user does have the correct permissions as the entity lists render as expected.  When removing the entity permissions the chart does show the correct error message.
The following liquid code is an example from the template

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 hide-chart-legend">
  <!-- Est. Revenue by Est. Close Date (Day) - Opportunities Closing Next Month -->
  {% chart id:"EB02E9AA-5580-E611-80D8-00155DFE75F9" viewid:"00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010003002" %}
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 small" data-entitygrid-layout="compact">
  <!-- Distributed Opportunities -->
  {% include "entity_list" key:"distributed-opportunities" %}
</div>
```

This code renders the following:

[image: Dashboard rendered on Partner portal]

Comment: Defo V8 of Dynamics? Are you on-premise?

Comment: Are you sure those Ids are correct?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/configure/add-chart

Comment: We are using v8 on-premise.  I did check the Ids and they are correct.

Comment: What portal are you using?

Comment: We are using the Partner Portal from Adxstudio Portals 7.0